# Explaining IIFE Inside Loop

Tags: javascript

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) article, but I have some issues understanding it.

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function IIFE(arg) {
        funcs[arg] = function output() {
            console.log("My value: " + arg);
        };
    })(i);
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();
}
```

How can I explain the mechanism of this snippet?

Start: `i` has value of `0`. IIFE gets the value of `i` and stores it in `arg`.

`funcs[0]` just get assigned to a function named `output`.

second time, when `i` is 1, funcs[1] gets a totally new function? Is this false?

.....

The problem is here, How does `funcs[0]();` know that `arg` was 0? How things interact?

Function `output()` looks up and ask `IIFE function` to give the required value? right? Can someone say which illustration is correct?

[image: IIFE]

By Providing this picture, for example, number 1, I mean, when `funcs[0]()` gets executed, output looks for `arg`, it doesn't find it, then goes to higher scope and finds it. each function has it's own IIFE, for example. I'n not sure how far are this from Javascript or even programming world, but help me get it!

Comment: It's all about closures... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: And picture #1 is correct. Maybe it gets clearer if you omit the name "output" from the innermost functions. It's a new function for every loop

Comment: Illustration 1 is fine. But notice that it's not so much about functions being "nested", the important thing is about *scopes*. Multiple calls to even the same function will create multiple different scopes.

Comment: *"second time, when `i` is 1, `funcs[1]` gets a totally new function?"* Exactly correct, it gets a new function. *"How does `funcs[0]();` know that `arg` was 0? How things interact?"* Because `funcs[0]` has a reference to the execution context of the call to your anonymous function that created it, which contains the `arg` related to that call. Each function created and stored in `funcs` is a *closure* over its specific `arg`. There are multiple `arg`s (one per call). See the dupetarget and MysterX's link for details.

Comment: @Bergi: Not *scope*, execution context and associated binding object. But it's a fairly pedantic point, like formal parameter (the thing declared on the function) vs. argument (the thing it actually receives).